# What is the best way to export data in csv or xlsx

Tags: php, csv, xlsx

I used xlsx and csv to export data, it is working fine for me, but have just one concern with the time as records increasing, right now we have 50k+ records and it is taking almost 4-5 mins, in future the records will go on the time of export will goes on, so what can be the best solution to export data, any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel). PHPExcel - OpenXML - Read, Write and Create spreadsheet documents in PHP - Spreadsheet engine

***Or you can use***

**PHP Part :**

```
<?php
/*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "username"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "password";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "databasename";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "tablename"; //MySQL Table Name   
$filename = "excelfilename";         //File Name
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
//create MySQL connection   
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }   
?>
```

Comment: You are welcome hope so it works for you. If yes, you can approve my answer right and relevant.

Answer (score 1):

**Comma-Separated Values (CSV)** :    These files hold plain text as a series of values (cells) separated by commas (,) in a series of lines (rows). You can actually open a CSV file in a text editor and read it yourself. Many applications are capable of reading CSV files, and many languages provide built-in functions that simplify reading/writing CSV format.

**Excel (represented as XL) Spreadsheet (XLS)** :  It is an MS Excel workbook binary file, which holds information about all the worksheets in a workbook, comprising both content and formatting (number masking, colouring, conditional formatting, etc), and can also hold additionals like charts, images, etc. XLS files can only be read by applications that have been especially written to read their format, and can only be written in the same way.

> So if you want to use it for saving purpose only than use csv , for formatting , calculating  or other processes.. use xslx..